# Securing the interval in uniroot()?

Tags: r, function, optimization, solver

I was wondering if I could make `uniroot()` work for when `q` is between nearly `0` and `2`?

Currently, `uniroot()` works only for `q > = 3`.

**P.S.** I changed the interval limits, as well as using `extendInt = "downX"` in `uniroot()`, none of which worked.

**Here is my R code:**

```
f <- function(x, alpha = .05, q = 2, df1 = 3, df2 = 108){
 alpha - suppressWarnings(pf(q, df1, df2, x, lower.tail = FALSE))
}

curve(f)

sapply(c(.05, .95), 
function(i) uniroot(f, interval = c(0, 2e2), alpha = i, q = 2, df1 = 3, df2 = 108)[[1]])
```

Comment: what have you tried so far?  does plotting the curves give you any hints about what's not working, or how to solve the problem? Have you tried with `extendInt` as in my previous answer?

Comment: @BenBolker, Ben, I guess the problem is with `alpha = .05`. But I don't have the expertise to exactly determine what to fix. I changed the interval limits, as well as changing `extendInt`, none of which worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that for the values you have specified (alpha=0.05, q=2, df1=3, df2=108), the cumulative distribution function doesn't seem to attain the value you want for any value of the non-centrality parameter (your `x`).

```
f <- function(x, alpha = .05, q = 2, df1 = 3, df2 = 108){
  alpha - suppressWarnings(pf(q, df1, df2, x, 
                              lower.tail = FALSE))
}
```

You can see this most easily by looking at the curve:

```
png("c1.png")
curve(f(x,alpha=0.05,q=2,df1=3,df2=108),
      from=1e-8,to=2e2,log="x")
dev.off()
```

[image]

(The curve starts off negative at `x=0` and decreases ...)

Brute force exploration of what happens for varying alpha, ncp, q ...

```
library(ggplot2)
dd <- expand.grid(alpha=seq(0.025,0.975,by=0.025),
                  q=seq(2,4.75,by=0.25),
                  x=emdbook::lseq(1e-2,2e2,length.out=51))
dd$z <- c(plyr::aaply(dd,1,
            function(z) with(z,f(alpha=alpha,q=q,x=x))))
ggplot(dd,aes(x,alpha,z=z))+geom_raster(aes(fill=z))+
  facet_wrap(~q,labeller=label_both)+
  scale_x_log10(expand=c(0,0))+
  scale_y_continuous(expand=c(0,0))+
  geom_contour(breaks=0,colour="red")+
  geom_hline(yintercept=c(0.05,0.95),
             colour="magenta",lty=2)
ggsave("c2.png")
```

The red curves are zero contours: the horizontal dashed lines are the transects along which you're trying to find roots. You can see that for low `q` the transects don't intersect the contour.

What this means in statistical terms is not something I've thought about ...

[image]